# Symfony 6.0 time format problem database upload

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

There were some problems with symfony over time. unfortunately, this is not the first time I have run into this. Has anyone ever encountered this problem? If so, thank you for your help.

**Controller.php**

```
  if($xml = simplexml_load_file($feedUrl)) {
            $result["chanel"] = $xml->xpath("/rss/channel/item");

            foreach($result as $key => $attribute) {
                $i=0;

                foreach($attribute as $element) {


                    $ret[$i]['title'] = (string)$element->title;
                    $ret[$i]['category'] = (string)$element->category;
                    $ret[$i]['link'] = (string)$element->link;
                    $ret[$i]['pubDate'] = json_decode(json_encode($element->pubDate), TRUE);
                    $ret[$i]['enclosure'] = (array)$element->enclosure;
                    $ret[$i]['description'] = (string)$element->description;

                    $i++;
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($ret as $feed){

        $newnews = new Newsfeed();

        $newnews->setTitle($feed['title']);
        $newnews->setCategory($feed['category']);
        $newnews->setLink($feed['link']);
        $newnews->setDescription($feed['description']);
        $newnews->setDate(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", strtotime($feed['pubDate'][0])));
        $newnews->setImage($feed['enclosure']['@attributes']['url']);
        $newnews->setSource('2');

            $entityManager->persist($newnews);
            $entityManager->flush();


        }
```

**This problem**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`date()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) function returns a string, so this line won't work:

```
$newnews->setDate(date("Y-m-d h:i:sa", strtotime($feed['pubDate'][0])));
```

You can probably just use:

```
$newnews->setDate(new \DateTimeImmutable($feed['pubDate'][0]));
```

Answer (score -1):

I have had this problem before. For me, when working with only Dates (no time) it was kind of misleading the fact that MySQL and thus `doctrine annotations` have the `Date` type, but PHP/Symfony does not.

As mentioned by Chris, the `date()` function returns a string, but the class [DateTime](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) is your friend here.

Even when it is called DateTime, this class allows [formatting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) and you can indeed, for example, retrieve only a date with it. An example would be:

```
$date = new DateTime('2000-01-01 12:30:25');
echo $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

Or **in your case, in which you DO want to return the time part** too:

```
$pubDate = new DateTime($feed['pubDate'][0])->format('Y-m-d h:i:sa');
$newnews->setDate($pubDate);
```

Which can be easily transformed into a one-liner.

This will show only what you ask for in the `format()` function.

There is one trickiness though. In my country at least, it is very common to format dates with a slash (`/`), but `DateTime->format()` will not work with `Y/m/d`, so keep it in mind and check for the correct format [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.date.php) if you are going to be using slashes.